# Finding the CNF of PL formula

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have this expression and I'm trying to find the CNF for it.

(P ∨ (Q↔R))∧¬(Q→R)

I have followed the steps of simplification until the distribution of "V". This is my current expression:

(P ∨ ((¬Q ∨ R) ∧ (¬R ∨ Q))) ∧ Q ∧ ¬R

If someone could help me how I distribute this and get the simplest form of the CNF that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  Now apply the distributive law $$A \lor (B \land C)=(A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$$ with
$A=P$, $B=\lnot Q \lor R$, and $C=\lnot R \lor Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try and use this.